# uninstaller doesn't delete all installed files

Tags: install4j

We have a strange problem during our uninstall process.
After the uninstaller finishes, the user custom sources and some parts of the jre are still present on the system. In the uninstaller.log it states the postponed deletion of some of these files, but not all of them.
Has someone an idea why the deletion is postponed and why they are not deleted at all?

Additionally that doesnt happen on all systems, but is reproducable per system. For example on my developer machine everything works fine, but on a fresh vm the problem occurs.

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.UninstallFilesAction [ID 29]: Execute action
       executing auto uninstall
       postponing deletion of C:\Program Files (x86)\mytool\jre\lib\rt.jar
       postponing deletion of C:\Program Files (x86)\mytool\.install4j\user.jar
       postponing deletion of C:\Program Files (x86)\mytool\.install4j\i4jruntime.jar
       postponing deletion of C:\Program Files (x86)\mytool\jre\lib\resources.jar
       postponing deletion of C:\Program Files (x86)\mytool\jre\lib\jsse.jar
       postponing deletion of C:\Program Files (x86)\mytool\jre\lib\charsets.jar
       postponing deletion of C:\Program Files (x86)\mytool\jre\lib\jce.jar
       postponing deletion of C:\Program Files (x86)\mytool\jre\lib\jfr.jar
       postponing deletion of C:\Program Files (x86)\mytool\.install4j\user\myaction.jar
       Execute action successful after 717 ms
```

my first guess was that it has something to do with the user action. but this is part of the automatic updater which is not executed at all.

**edit:**

after adding an action "Check for running processes" it is still the same behaviour.

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.CheckRunningProcessesAction [ID 738]: Execute action
       Property additionalExecutables: null
       Property closeStrategy: Allow soft close
       Property message: install4j hat entdeckt, dass mytool zur Zeit ausgeführt wird.

Bitte schließen Sie jetzt die folgenden Instanzen, und klicken Sie auf "Wiederholen", um fortzufahren, oder auf "Abbrechen", um zu beenden.
       Property timeOut: 5000
       Property allowIgnore: false
       Property includeLaunchers: true
       Property rollbackSupported: true
       Execute action successful after 0 ms
```

My assumption from this log message is, there were no running processes, as the action is completed after 0 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

This means that a launcher that is using the bundled JRE is still running. Some files in the JRE are locked in that case and they cannot be deleted.

Use a "Check for running processes" action in the uninstaller to shut down all launchers before the "Uninstall files" action is executed.

Comment: Are you talking about a Launcher defined in the project? Because we dont even start anything after the installation and uninstall immeditately. What else could lock the jre? And why does it occur only on some specific systems?

Adding the Action didnt change anything unfortunately.

Comment: You could try process explorer  to find out who is locking the files https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer